# Detecting people crossing a line with OpenCV

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, video-processing, emgucv

I want to count number of people crossing a line from either side. I have a camera that is placed on ceiling and shooting for the floor where the line is (So camera sees just top of people heads; and so it is more of object detection than people detection).

Is there any sample solution for this problem or similar problems like this? So I can learn from them?

Edit 1: More than one person is crossing the line at any moment.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to add any more tags to your question?

Comment: Actually I am a C# developer and I found Emgu which is a cross platform .NET wrapper for OpenCV. So I am going to use C#. But I thought it would be inappropriate to add other tags like C#. And I appreciate if you suggest other tags; thanks in advance.

Comment: There you go, add: C#, Emgu, video-processing

Comment: Is there some reason you *must* use OpenCV and a video camera? Infrared photodetectors that do exactly what you describe are available at hardware stores for under $100.

Comment: @Dour High Arch There is no "must" here. If it is as you say then I should be happy and further guidance is more than appreciated! I did not know about those cameras and my only musts are described in the question: The line and the moving circles (people heads, maybe covered by hat or something). Thanks again!

Comment: @Kaveh, photodetectors are extremely common in my home city. Most work by detecting interruptions in infrared beams, and are used for things like counting customers or opening doors. You can get detectors with cameras, but what you describe does not need one unless there are requirements you are not telling us. You could start by searching Google: http://www.google.ca/search?q=photoelectric+beam+sensor

Comment: That's not an option unfortunately! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing else but humans are subject to cross the line then you need not to detect people you only have to detect motion.
There are several approaches for motoin detection.

Probably the simplest one fits your goals. You simply calculate difference between successive frames of video stream and this way determine "motion mask" and thus detect line crossing event

As an improvement of this "algorithm" you may consider "running average" method.

To determine a direction of motion you can use "motion templates".

In order to increase accuracy of your detector you may try any background subtraction technique (which in turn is not a simple solution). For example, if there is some moving background which should be filtered out (e.g. using statistical learning)

All algorithms mentioned are included in OpenCV library.

UPD:

- [how to compute motion mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756690/finding-image-silhouette-using-opencv/4759556#4759556)
- Useful functions for determining motion direction `cvCalcMotionGradient`, `cvSegmentMotion`, `cvUpdateMotionHistory` ([search docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/search.html?q=motion&check_keywords=yes&area=default)). OpenCV library contains example code for motion analysis, see [motempl.c](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/c/motempl.c?rev=1429)
- [advanced background subtraction from "Learning OpenCV" book](http://books.google.com/books?id=seAgiOfu2EIC&pg=PA265&lpg=PA265&dq=opencv%20background%20subtraction&source=bl&ots=hSD3ehjHOe&sig=MuQ6EV00kBV11Bnx3nnMdwVNafs&hl=en&ei=qV-4TcngG4WhOv6ojJAP&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&sqi=2&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=opencv%20background%20subtraction&f=false)

Comment: I do not know the name of these algorithms in OpenCV or any kind of samples for it. Any hint would be very useful. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer. By the way reading sample code included to OpenCV library makes life easier

Comment: Its rather upsetting how there is no open source EMG

Comment: It is rather upsetting how there is no open source sample project that would just show how to do pedestrian tracking with OpenCV (or crossing the line at least). There are tons of videos on YouTube and a lot of theoretical talk on how it's done, but no actual implemented example. If you ever find one, please publish it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in video-based cv, but if you can reduce the problem into a finite set of images (for instance, entering frame, standing on line, exiting frame), then you can use one of many shape recognition algorithms. I know of Shape Context which is good, but I doubt if it subtle enough for this application (it won't tell the difference between a head and most other round objects).

Basically, try to extract key images from the video, and then test them with shape recognition algorithms.

P.S. Finding the key images might be possible with good motion detection methods.