# how to Track object from video using c#

Tags: c#, tracking

I'm trying to code a project in which I track a tennis ball across a court after a serve and work out its speed. The user uploads a video of them serving and then the program works it out. Is it possible to track an object within an uploaded video using C#? And is it also possible to identify the lines of the court?

Comment: Yes, it is. But I get the feeling it won't be a very accurate speed measurement, if you have a top-view of the court you're pretty far away from the ball. But if you film with 50p FullHD, there might be a chance.

Comment: The video would be filmed from behind the player, so the ball is always in sight (apart from when it's behind the net tape).

Comment: From behind the player sounds like the worst possible angle for figuring out the speed of the ball. You need to see the ball moving across the image.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10248/Motion-Detection-Algorithms

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5806827/detecting-people-crossing-a-line-with-opencv

Answer (score 3):

Its 18.29 meters from the baseline to the service line. If we assume a ball speed of 100 mph (slower than [in Wimbledon](http://www.wimbledon.com/en_GB/scores/extrastats/speed_ws.html) and nowhere near what I see on hobby courts), the ball needs 0.4 seconds from the baseline to the service line (completely disregarding the drop in speed after it is hit by the racket).
If you film with 25fps, you will have a ball on circa 10 single pictures. 
Filming from the top, I'd say motion blur will make it almost impossible to correctly track it and approximate the speed. 
Filming from behind, thinking about motion blur, the net, the player, the racket... I'd say, it's near impossible.

Try [one of these](http://www.ebay.com/sch/Radar-Guns-Speed-Sensors-/73916/i.html).

Comment: How about 50fps, as you mention in your first comment?

Comment: Let me recalculate. Wait. 20 pictures! Just don't film interlaced. Still, filming from behind, how would you see the court lines?

Comment: I'm not the OP, I'm just being hypothetical and curious. So viewed from the side and filmed at 50fps non-interlaced, it might be possible?

Comment: Filmed from the top, with maybe 50fps full frame, I'd think you can get a good approximation. But then, physics kick in. The ball drops in speed a fraction after being touched by the racket. I don't know how Wimbledon does it, expect they use radar, but at what point do you take the measurement?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know OPEN CV ? http://opencv.org/

I think you can use it with C#

Comment: Beat you by 1 second!  :-)

Comment: OpenCV from C#: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page